# JQuery UI Tabs break in secure (https) page

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, user-interface, https

I'm using the out-of-the-box JQuery UI tabs- they work fine on an unsecured page but not on the secure https:// page.

I'm calling my scripts like this:

```
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Examples here:
http://ntcla.com/fb-static.php and
https://ntcla.com/fb-static.php

(see map at the bottom of the page)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: TypeError: a.datepicker is undefined
https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
Line 5

Comment: Though I don't see tabs in either version in FF 14.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an SSL cert error on the code.jquery.com link.  You could just download it and host it on your own site/CDN.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate error will be thrown when you try using any js in following manner

download above files and copy them on your server and access them using relative paths on your script